# Castle Clash: Is there an optimal time to use gems to buy heroes?

Tags: castle-clash

I've been buying heroes with Gems but the chances of me getting Legendary heroes doesn't seem to be that great. Is there a "best" time of day or day of week or holiday period that I should be saving my gems to buy them at that time? Maybe something else is involved when purchasing heroes with gems that helps the chances? Please help.

Comment: This is very opinionated, but all you can do is hope you get lucky

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no optimal time to spend gems, there may eventually be an event that might help you with that but as far as I know, the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 2):

There's a discover the treasure event now and then. You will get a chance to win random awards by spending 2k gems. Personally I got 3 cupids out of the event. Now hero collector is the new thing, but you gotta save around 60k gems to worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following strategy usually, when in the lost world I get a purple bag of  pinnacle or golden key fighting or in a chest, I try if I'm lucky, I managed a large number of legendary heroes in this form.